# Android in-app purchase Pro Status

Tags: android, android-billing

I am building a android app which i would like to have in-app billing for.

I would just like to ask a general question about i-app purchases and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

If i want my app to have Pro users, which would be an in app purchase to unlock parts of the app, how would one go about doing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely use [Managed In-app Products](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#managed).

Once the product is purchased do not consume it. Google Play Services keep track of all purchased products and syncs it between devices. You just check if user owns given product and disable/enable pro features based on the response.

Comment: This is where i get lost disable/enable features, would i store the status of the user being pro in something like shared preferences once i get the sucessfull return from the play store, then if that user has pro status when that part of the app loads he will be allowed to procced?

Comment: You don't need to store it. Just query the IAP inventory for purchases and check whether or not to unlock the pro features.